# Gravar dados de Tabela Hmtl no Banco | Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-datatables

Estou com uma dúvida com relação a recuperar as informações de uma tabela html e salvar no banco de dados utilizando laravel.

Esta parte da aplicação consiste em armazenar em uma tabela user_exame informações relacionadas a exames que este usuário deverá realizar.

Na tabela eu armazeno o user_id, exame_id, dt_utlimo_exame, dt_proximo_exame

Estou populando a tabela html com o seguindo código:

```js
eventsForm: function(){ 

    jQuery('#btn-adicionar-exame').click(function(){

 moment.locale('pt-br');

 var id = jQuery('#exame').find('option:selected').val();
 var exame = jQuery('#exame').find('option:selected').text();
 var periodical = jQuery('#periodical').find('option:selected').val();
 var periodicalText = jQuery('#periodical').find('option:selected').text();
 var ultimoExame = jQuery('#dtUltimoExame').val();
 var newRow = $("<tr>"); 
 var cols   = "";
 var proximoExame = '';
   
 //Define a proxima data do exame
 proximoExame = moment(ultimoExame, "DD/MM/YYYY").add(periodical, 'months');

 cols += '<td>' + id + '</td>';
 cols += '<td>' + exame + '</td>';
 cols += '<td>' + periodicalText + '</td>';
 cols += '<td>' + ultimoExame + '</td>';
 cols += '<td>' + moment(proximoExame, "DD/MM/YYYY").calendar() + '</td>';
   
 cols += '<td>';
 cols += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link " id="btn-delet" onclick="employee.removeTableRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-1x color-red"></i></button>';
 cols += '</td>';

 newRow.append(cols);
   
 /Adicionando a row a tabela
 jQuery("#table-list-exames").append(newRow);

        //Limpando os campos
 jQuery('#exame').val("").change();
 jQuery('#periodical').val("").change();
 jQuery('#dtUltimoExame').val('');

});
},
```

Minha dúvida é: como recuperar cada linha da tabela e armazenar no banco utilizando o Laravel?

Sei que em javascript poderia fazer algo como:

```js
tableExames.find('tr').each(function (i) {...}
```

mas como fazer isso no controller do Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que fazer um ajax para cada linha incluída nessa tabela aí. Para fazer isso, use um seletor para as linhas da tabela: `$('#table-list-exames tr')` e aí é só usar o `each` do jQuery para pegar as informações:

```js
$('#table-list-exames tr').each(function(i, linha){
   // pega as colunas de cada linha
   var colunas = $(linha).find('td'); 
   // transforma em um objeto
  var registro = {};
  $(colunas).each(function(j, col){
    registro[j] = $(col).text();
  });
  console.log(registro);
  // manda por ajax pro servidor
  //cadastrar_exame(registro);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="table-list-exames">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Claro, trate os dados antes de mandar por Ajax. Precisando de ajuda com o Ajax, essa documentação do jQuery é bem legal: http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.post

Comment: Só percebi depois que sua pergunta é sobre a parte de controllers do Laravel. Foi mal... mas uma vez que você trate os dados, a parte de backend não é nenhuma loucura, né?

Comment: Sem problemas. Ainda não consegui encontrar a solução. Pensei em chamar uma função javascript pelo evento onclick ao invés de dar um submit no form. Nesta função eu recuperaria as informações da tabela e armazenaria em um objeto. Depois chamaria o método do controller passando este objeto. Bom, não sei se funcionaria e nem se seria a forma correta. Chagando em casa tentarei fazer isso.

Comment: Então, essa solução que descrevi faria a parte de enviar os dados para o PHP usando ``Ajax``, só não coloquei a parte de enviar pro servidor usando Javascript, por que achei que seria muita coisa. Uma vez que você envie usando o ``jQuery.post`` não tem erro, vai chegar lá como se fosse um array normal de PHP, ficando dentro da variável $_POST. A parte de Laravel que eu não sei, pois nunca usei essa framework.

Comment: Pessoal, ainda não consegui resolver meu problema. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O que tá rolando? Tem que dar os detalhes, cara, a gente não é telepata :)

De qualquer forma, melhor fazer uma nova pergunta, a menos que você ainda esteja com o mesmo problema.